# RAILS/HTML: Change image slide every 7 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen a lot of questions like mine here in stack just like these three: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926650/javascript-after-7-seconds-slide-image), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586553/making-a-image-slider-that-changes-images-every-6-seconds) and [3](http://3). But I tried their way but it didn't work.

I am looking for a more simple way.
Using Javascript in-line in html, I tried to have this code (which I found in one of those questions here in stack)

```
<script>
function FetchData() {
  $("#pack").animate({
      left: '-1000px'
  }, 'slow');
}
setTimeout(FetchData, 7000); </script>
```

and have this as well...

```
<img id="pack" src="image.jpg">
```

but it seems to not work. Nothing happened. I have looked and stared at the photo for over a minute and it did not move at all. What was wrong? Do I lack some codes? I have no css code that relates to this by the way.

Comment: why is there a downvoter who'd not explain why this post deserves a down vote??? i accept a down vote but it has to come with explanation.

Comment: When you say you're not allowed to use **inline** javascript, does that mean you can have a javascript include tag to a js file instead?  Why are you not allowed - is this your homework, to do it without js?

Comment: @MaxWilliams yes! we are just told to separate js and html. but since in inline my code is not working, it won't also work when separated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use carousel using bootstrap and put this on the topmost part of your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is the code for the slides in html:

```
            <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel">
                    </li>
                    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel">
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <%= image_tag 'image_1.jpg' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <%= image_tag 'image_2.jpg' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <%= image_tag 'image_3.jpg' %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

and this is the javascript in-line code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myCarousel").carousel({
            interval : 7000,
            pause: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your teacher says "separate js and html", and that you shouldn't use inline javascript, they probably mean that you should have something like this setup:

in your layout, include a javascript file (this might be included by default).  It's best to put these down the bottom.  If there's a default layout it might have a place for javascript includes already.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

in your view

```
<img id="pack" src="image.jpg">
```

in application.js

```
$(function() {
  //run on dom ready
  console.log("about to setTimeout");
  setTimeout(FetchData, 7000);
  console.log("done setTimeout");
});

function FetchData() {
  console.log("in FetchData, about to animate, $('#pack').size() = "+$('#pack').size());
  $("#pack").animate({
      left: '-1000px'
  }, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: it did not work. nothing will happen. as if it did not execute. what could be the problem?

Comment: Look in the "Console" tab in your chrome debug panel, or the equivalent in whatever browser you use.  Are there any errors there?   I've just edited my question to do some logging to the console which should help debug it.

Comment: Also note that i have no idea whether your `animate` call will work - your question was just about how to organise the javascript.    It seems a bit odd to animate a slide when you only have a single image.